# How to implement the lazy loading for listing of n number of records like Gmail app loading in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

I'm getting n number of records at a time when hit the web service due to this performance of the app was too bad ,so I need to implement lazy loading in my app to show the n number of records as like as Gmail app functionality to increase the performance of my app ,so anyone plz help me .

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach is infinite scroll which you can use either via the [InfiniteContainer](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/InfiniteContainer.html) or the `InfiniteScrollAdapter`.

There are discussions and samples for this including the property cross demo where you can see infinite scroll adapter in use with a webservice result.

You can see the component gallery for Codename One [here](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/package-summary.html).